# Showing different version of python in different user

Tags: python, update-alternatives

I have installed different versions of python in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have added those versions in 'update alternatives' for switching to a different version.

When I switch to another python version from other than root user using 'update alternatives', it works properly for that user but it doesn't work for the root user. It shows the previous version in root user when I switch to python using update alternative as a root user.

Comment: Hey Tanvir Rahman! In Ask Ubuntu, we recommend having code output as text (and format it as code; read [this](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for more information) instead of screenshot in the question. You can [edit] your question and copy paste the code and output. Also, consider going through the [tour] page.

Comment: I'm curious how you are running `update-alternatives` as a non-root user - it should require root because it's not setuid and it modifies symbolic links in `/etc`

Answer (score 0):

Each user on Ubuntu saves the default Python version independently from root or any other user. I have experienced this myself while having two users on one Ubuntu machine. Every new user created will have the system defaults (in everything, not just Python) when it is first created, regardless of what customized settings the root user may have.

Comment: It's because the desktop environment configuration is stored in the `.config` directory in `$HOME` (`/home/user`). Generally, each time you create a new user, a new Home directory is created with an empty `~/.config` so all the desktop configurations (and many more configs) are lost. On the other hand Python does not store it's configuration in HOME directory (if not manually configured as such). So, Python configs are not lost.